# Create function to logout in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

in the wordpress functions.php page, I enabled Session variables like this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['usuarioId'] = $user_ID;;
$_SESSION['usuarioNome'] = $user_identity;
$_SESSION['email'] = $user_email;
$_SESSION['login'] = $user_login;
function register_my_session(){
    if(! session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}
```

When logging out with the wordpress logout function, I don't destroy the sessions of the pages where I use them. I no longer have access to the wp-admin page, because I logged out, but on the pages where I have these sessions, the pages still have access.

I have this problem, I need to create a function to log out of the sit

Can you help?

Comment: Did you try hooking into [`wp_logout`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_logout/)?

Comment: @Chris Haas How do I turn on wp_logout?

Comment: That is a WordPress hook. See the comment on the documentation for that hook for a high level, or the [main documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/) for hooks in general

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the `wp_logout`. Per the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_logout/):

> Fires after a user is logged out.

```php
add_action(
    'wp_logout',
    function() {

        // Destroy PHP's relation to the session
        session_destroy();

        // Unset the global session variable, just in case they are used elsewhere
        $_SESSION = [];
    }
);
```

If you are using a theme, this code can be placed in `functions.php`, or anything that that file includes.

Make sure to read the documentation on [`session_destroy`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) to understand that it might not behave exactly as you expect, depending on when you call it.

Comment: I have the following button: `<a href="https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/login?action=logout">SAIR</span>`. I added the code above in functions.php, but when I logout, the session only ends even in wordpress, in the pages where I use the sessions, the session remains active

Comment: It is important to be clear and literal here. That link is not a core WordPress logout link, it should be `/wp-login.php?action=logout&_wpnonce=ABCDEFGH`. Can you confirm that your link is more like this? If so, change the code inside the function I posted to just include `die('test')` and then try logging out, just to make sure it is firing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
function wp_destroy_current_session() {
    $token = wp_get_session_token();
    if ( $token ) {
        $manager = WP_Session_Tokens::get_instance( get_current_user_id() );
        $manager->destroy( $token );
    }
}
```

Source: [`wp_destroy_current_session()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_destroy_current_session/)

Comment: The OP is saying that they are using PHP sessions, and when someone logs out of WordPress, they want their session destroyed, too. Can you explain how this code relates to that scenario? I would actually think your previous deleted answer would be much closer to what they'd want.

Comment: He can use this methode with the do_action(), normaly it will work ...I can undelete my late post if you want

Comment: WordPress doesn't actually use PHP sessions in core, they are custom session-like things that are cookie-bound. So there's nothing in core that can unset a PHP sessions. But, I think your previous answer, combined with a call to `session_destroy` would be what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Ok, and if so, could you help to create the combination between the action and the session_destroy